# linked list- loop goes to infinity

Tags: c++, linked-list, infinite-loop

Given below is the code I made for creation and display of a linked list. I  think the display method is causing the infinite loop to occur but I cannot figure out the reason. I compared with the codes available online and it looks okay. Why is this happening?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class NODE
{
    int data;
    NODE*next;
    NODE*start;
public:
      NODE()
      {
          start=NULL;
      }
      void in(int v);
      void display();
};

void NODE::in(int v)
{
    NODE*n;
    n=new NODE;
    n->data=v;
    n->next=NULL;
    if (start==NULL)
    {
        start=n;
    }
    else
    {
        NODE*p;
        p=start;
        while(p->next!=NULL)
        {
            p=p->next;
        }
        p->next=n;

        }
        cout<<"leaving the insert function";
    delete n;
}

void NODE::display()
{   
    cout<<"enters the display function";
    NODE*p;p=start;
    cout<<"data is-"<<'\n';
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<p->data<<"->";
        p=p->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    NODE ob;
    cout<<"enter the no. of values";
    int h;
    cin>>h;
    for(int i=0;i<h;i++)
        {
            cout<<"enter the value to be inserted";
            int v;
            cin>>v;
            ob.in(v);
        }
    ob.display();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Delete delete n in in

Comment: A little  odd to `delete` the very thing you just linked to your list, don't you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `delete` `n` in the `in` method, you should do it later if you want to use the object.

Also, you iterate over `p->next` but this value is never initialized so it certainly won't be `NULL` even for a new object!

Your `display` method looks good.

Maybe you should add a `LinkedList` class to manage all the nodes, and it's this object which will care about adding a new node.

Comment: Thank you. I removed my delete n statement and the code works but I didn't understand the second point. Should I do p->next =NULL before iterating over p->next in my in method?

Comment: You should initialize `next` in the constructor